# Acessing a datacontrol from a listview in asp.net c

Tags: c#, asp.net

I''ve been working at this for a good while now. I'm simply trying to access something that is in a datalist. I can get items just fine from the PageLoad, even set some dynamic items.. but I can't acess controls from my button click handler. 
I've tried other variations such as

```
ListView1.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
```

Which gives a NULL.
I've tried

```
<asp:LinkButton id="addPro" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text %>' onCommand ="addPro_Click">Add To Cart</asp:LinkButton>
```

Which says it can't find the data control in scope.

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
        DataKeyNames="Expr7,Expr1,productNo" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <span style="">
            <asp:Label ID="productNameLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("productName") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Image runat="server" height = "300" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("img") %>'></asp:Image>
            <br />
            Description:<br />
            <asp:Label ID="itemNotesLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemNotes") %>' />
            <br />

            stock:
            <asp:Label ID="stockLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("stock") %>' />
            <br />
            price:
            <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "$"+ Eval("price")+".00" %>' />
            <br />

            Quantitiy: <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>            
            <br />

            <asp:LinkButton id="addPro" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("productNo") %>' onCommand ="addPro_Click">Add To Cart</asp:LinkButton>
            <br /><br /><br />
<br /></span>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

On click

```
protected void addPro_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string addr = "";
    string v = Request.QueryString["cat"];
    if (v != null)
    {
        v = "cat=" + v+"&";
    }
    else
    {
        v = "";
    }

    DropDownList stockDD = (DropDownList) FindControl("DropDownList1");
    if (stockDD != null)
        addr = "~/product.aspx/?" + v + "add=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "&quant=" + stockDD.SelectedItem.Text;
    else
        addr = "ERROR!";
    Response.Redirect(addr+e.CommandArgument.ToString());        
    ListView1.ItemDataBound += (sa, ea) =>
        {
            DropDownList stockD = ea.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
            Label l = ea.Item.FindControl("Lable12") as Label;
            l.Text = stockD.SelectedItem.Text;
            addr = "~/product.aspx/?" + v + "add=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "&quant=" + stockD.SelectedItem;

        };
  // Response.Redirect(addr);
}
```

Any help in the right direction will help a ton! Thanks!

Comment: Note this isn't the final. In the end it will have the arguments ?add=9&quant=3 or a variation.

Comment: Try `(sender as LinkButton).Container.FindControl`

Comment: It doesn't accept the Container. I looked it up for a while, it looks like that's a VB command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
LinkButton lbSender = (LinkButton)sender;
ListViewDataItem lvItem = (ListViewDataItem)(lbSender.Parent);
DropDownList DropDownList1 = lvItem.FindControl("DropDownList1");
```

`ListView.Items` is a collection of `ListViewDataItem` which inherits `ListViewItem`, which inherits from `Control`. This means you can find any control in its `Controls` collection using `FindControl`. You just have to look at the heirarchy.

Docs for `ListView`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx

Docs for `ListViewDataItem`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewdataitem.aspx

Docs for `ListViewItem`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.aspx

Docs for `Control`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx

Comment: It worked, well once I removed a conversion from list button to dropdown.         LinkButton lbSender = (LinkButton)sender;
        DropDownList stockDD = (DropDownList)lbSender.FindControl("DropDownList1");